# eulervm with in xetex presentation with metropolis beamer theme

Tags: xetex, eulervm, siunits

I am unable to get the eulervm package working properly in this LaTeX beamer presentation (metropolis theme).

Normal math text gets the Fira Sans font and special symbols (e.g. the Omega in `\ohm` from SIUnits is not displayed, while `$\Omega$` is.

MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}                     % Use metropolis theme

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent]{eulervm} % after amsmath!
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[Gray,squaren,thinqspace,thinspace]{SIunits} % elegant units

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Alternative Approach: Ramp Generator}
  \centering
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[R,l=\unit{10}{\kilo\ohm}] ++(2,0);
  \end{circuitikz}

  Euler? $\forall x \in \mathcal{R}$. No!

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the SIunits package to siunitx (and `\unit` by `\SI`):

```
\usepackage{siunitx} % elegant units
\sisetup{
    detect-mode,
    group-digits            = false,
    input-symbols           = ( ) [ ] - +,
    table-align-text-post   = false,
    input-signs             = ,
    %%decimalsymbol=comma, %% not needed, as implied by `locale=DE` option
    locale = UK,
    }
```